# segmentation fault fork and semaphores

Tags: c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, fork, semaphore

I'm trying to calculate: [1 2] * [1 2]' meaning 1*1+2*2=5 using vectors a[2] = {1, 2} and b[2] = {1, 2}
I want to do it using processes and semaphores in c, I create 2 processes with fork, let's call them process1 and process 2, process one creates another 2 processes one that does 1*1 and the other one that does 2*2. Process two should wait for processes in process 1 to end and then calculate the sum of the results.
When I compile with  gcc filename.c -lpthread -lrt I get seg fault, when I compile with -gcc filename.c -lpthread -lrt -fsanitize=address the output is:
calc1
calc2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char* mem_a_vect = "a_vect";
    const char* mem_b_vect = "b_vect";
    int id_mem_a, id_mem_b, id_mem_x, id_mem_y, id_mem_c;
    char *virt_addr_a, *virt_addr_b, *virt_addr_x, *virt_addr_y, *virt_addr_c;
    sem_t* semaphore;
    int shared_between_processes = 1;
    int* value;

    int a[2] = {1, 2};
    int b[2] = {1, 2};
    int c, x, y;
    *value = 0;


    id_mem_a = shm_open(mem_a_vect, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
    if (id_mem_a < 0)
    {
        printf("Eroare la CREAREA memoriei partajate a vectorului A\n");
    printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }
    virt_addr_a = mmap(a, 2 * sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, id_mem_a, 0);
    if (virt_addr_a == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Eroare la ATASAREA memoriei partajate a vectorului A\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(0);
    }
    id_mem_b = shm_open(mem_b_vect, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
    if (id_mem_b < 0)
    {
        printf("Eroare la CREAREA memoriei partajate a vectorului B\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    virt_addr_b = mmap(b, 2 * sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, id_mem_b, 0);
    if (virt_addr_b == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Eroare la ATASAREA memoriei partajate a vectorului B\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    id_mem_x = shm_open("x", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
    if (id_mem_x < 0)
    {
        printf("Eroare la CREAREA memoriei partajate a X\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    virt_addr_x = mmap(&x, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, id_mem_x, 0);
    if (virt_addr_x == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Eroare la ATASAREA memoriei partajate a Y\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    id_mem_y = shm_open("y", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
    if (id_mem_y < 0)
    {
        printf("Eroare la CREAREA memoriei partajate a Y\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    virt_addr_y = mmap(&y, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, id_mem_y, 0);
    if (virt_addr_y == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Eroare la ATASAREA memoriei partajate a Y\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    id_mem_c = shm_open("c", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
    if (id_mem_c < 0)
    {
        printf("Eroare la CREAREA memoriei partajate a X\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }
    virt_addr_c = mmap(&c, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, id_mem_c, 0);
    if (virt_addr_c == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("Eroare la ATASAREA memoriei partajate a C\n");
        printf("error code: %d\nerror text: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
    }

    sem_init(semaphore, shared_between_processes, 0);

    if (fork())
    {
    if (fork())
        {
            printf("calc 1 \n");
            x = a[0] * b[0];
            sem_post(semaphore);
        }
        else
        {
            y = a[1] * b[1];
            printf("calc 2\n");
            sem_post(semaphore);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        printf("wait");
        sem_wait(semaphore);
        sem_wait(semaphore);
        c = x + y;
    printf("Rezultatul inmultirii: %d\n", c);       
    }

    close(id_mem_a);
    close(id_mem_b);
    close(id_mem_x);
    close(id_mem_y);
    close(id_mem_c);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: after compiling and running your code I get a segfault at line 24: `*value = 0` because `value` is an uninitialized integer pointer defined few lines earlier.

Comment: thanks for finding that, but still in the last process that with printf("wait"); the program never enters, cant figure why